# Spring data neo4j : findByPropertyValue returns null (even after indexing)

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have a User Node class which looks like this:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {

    @GraphId 
    Long nodeId;

    @Indexed(unique = true,indexName="uid")
    Long uid;

    String name;

    @RelatedTo(type="FRIENDS", direction=Direction.BOTH)
    Set<User> friends;

    @RelatedToVia(type="FRIENDS", elementClass=IsFriends.class)
    Set<IsFriends> friendRelationships;

    @RelatedTo(type="LIKES", direction=Direction.OUTGOING)
    Set<Article> article;

    @RelatedToVia(type="LIKES", elementClass=Reco.class)
    Set<Likes> likeRelationships;

    //getters and setters

    ..
    ..

}
```

In my controller class, I have injected the repo like this:

```
@Inject
private UserRepository userRepo;
```

I am trying to retrieve a User object using the following :

```
User user = userRepo.findByPropertyValue("uid", userId);
```

I have 2 users in my graph, the above object retrieval works for one, but fails for the other. If I run a cypher query, I do see both the nodes.

Both the nodes were created using Spring Data Neo4j.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The User repository needs to also implement **NamedIndexRepository<>** because your index is named:

```
public interface UserRepository extends NamedIndexRepository<User> {
```

}

and then search including the name of the index:

```
User user = userRepo.findByPropertyValue("uid","uid", userId);
```